# sonar sensor Gazebo-ROS

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-sensor

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello Team,

I am using the plugin hector_gazebo_ros_sonar.so of the package hector_gazebo_plugins but the performance is very bad.

My problem is describe here: link:[here](http://answers.ros.org/question/43025/hector-sonar/)

I am looking for another sensor which works a little better. Anybody know another sonar sensor plugin?

It is to do a study to explain the best position of these sonar sensors around the robot vs Kinect in some cases.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/35/sonar-sensor-gazebo-ros/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/10/pmarinplaza/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2012-10-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2012-10-05**:
Is the problem that the sonar values jump, and then slowly extend back to the ground plane?

**Comment by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/10/pmarinplaza/) on 2012-11-06**:
Yes. The people of Hector fix the problem and it works very well now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Quoting from @pmarinplaza's comment:

Yes. The people of Hector fix the problem and it works very well now.

---

Originally posted by [gerkey](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/74/gerkey/) with karma: 1414 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0